# TFS command-line diff between server folders

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I'm probably being immensely dense here, but I can't see how to do what I'm trying to do.

I want a recursive diff between two server folders with a text (ie Unified) output.  I've tried this:

```
tf diff /recursive $/A/B $/A/Branch/B /format:Unified
Unable to determine the workspace.  You may be able to correct this by running 'tf workspaces /collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl'.
```

Switching to a workspace folder and trying the same command just says that all of the files only appear in the branch.

`tf folderdiff` does almost what I want - except that the only option for output is the graphical folder difference view.  I'm looking for something more like the output of `diff -r`.

Is this possible?  Am I missing something?

BTW I am using TFS 2010 Server and Visual Studio / Team Explorer 2013.

Comment: With VS2013 talking to TFS2010 you are right on the edge of support. You should upgrade TFS!

Answer (score 0):

Tf folderdiff /i will print text output but not in the format you want. You can parse that output and call tf diff for each file that was found different. Should be quite trivial.
Hope this help!